# Gunicore error running Docker - reviewed previous related post and still unable to fix

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I was able to build in Docker, but when I run I get error:/bin/sh: 1: [gunicorn,:not found
This happens after " docker run the-name-of-my-project " .

I tried suggestions in previous post:

1. docker build --no-cache the-name-of-my-project  (path"the-name-of-my-project" not found )
2. docker build --no-cache -t the-name-of-my-project ( invalid arguement, build requires exactly 1 arguement).

Any clue on how to deal with this gunicorn error?

Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown - 
R appuser /app
USER appuser
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:undefined", 
"ImageProcessingProgram\app_code_and_POST_call\post_call:app"]
```

Output: error:/bin/sh: 1: [gunicorn,:not found

[image]

[image]

Comment: An error that looks like `[gunicorn,` usually means that you tried to write a JSON-array [exec format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` line, but the command isn't actually a valid JSON array (using the wrong kind of quotes or missing quotes could cause this, for example).  I'd be very surprised if `docker build` produced PNG files, though; what code created the images you included in the question?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for responding. Actually the top image is the Dockerfile itself. The latest version of Docker VSC extensions actually pre populates a lot of it. The only thing I changed is the CMD line 25 ( that last line ) by plugging in the path of my own file. But the " :app " part was prepopulated.  So to answer your question, if gunicorn is related to the CMD then that code is the first pic.

Comment: Dockerfiles are plain-text files, not PNG-format images.  In the image it looks like parts of the lines are missing.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with the actual text of the Dockerfile and the output you're getting?

Comment: David, I added to actual code of the Dockerfile and the error message. Thanks for looking!

Comment: The argument to `gunicorn` is a Python `module:function` name, where the `module` will be dot-separated Python name.  Do you need to say something like `ImageProcessingProgram.app_code_and_POST_call.post_call:app`, with dots instead of backslashes?  If a backslash is right, it needs to be escaped with two backslashes in this context; the error is because `\a` and `\p` aren't valid JSON character escapes.